# c daemon runtime shell parameters

Tags: c, ipc, daemon

I'd develop a daemon that can be controlled by means of shell commands.
Just to clarify let's say that the daemon will have three functions (the invoke I'd like to have):

$ myDaemon start #do nothing, just daemonize. exit(0) is success, exit(1) otherwise

$ myDaemon stop #ask to the daemon to stop. exit(0) is success, exit(1) otherwise

$ myDaemon doSomething #ask to the daemon. exit(0) is success, exit(1) otherwise (let's say the daemon do int a = 0; exit(0); just to see the code, not interested in special stuffs)

may anyone kindly show me an example on how to produce this daemon (ok, start is really simple...)?

thanks all!

Comment: Here you go: http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html

Comment: Thanks Philip, but this useful guide you indicate (really good anyway) doesn't answer to my questions. I need someting like "$ myDaemon doSomething" I need a mechanism to pass to my daemon commands and to wait for answers (IPC).

Comment: Command line arguments would probably do the trick: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html#Parsing-Program-Arguments.   If you want your program to take input, do something, and then return the result and exit, then you're not really looking at a daemon, so much as a plain-jane regular program that takes input and spits output. Are you sure you need the program to run constantly in the background?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a daemon to do all the work, then one way is to write a terminal program to pass all the commands from the terminal to the daemon via some IPC technique.

All you have to do is:

- Write a terminal program which forks and then execl the daemon along with command line arguments( like file descriptors if using pipes).
- The terminal program then takes input in while loop from the terminal and passes them to the daemon through IPC mechanism in use.

**EDIT**

Algorithm for main process

```
main()
{
    > fork the daemon with some initial arguments(if any)
    while(1)
    {
        > take inputs from the shell
        > parse the input and pass it to daemon(via preferred mechanism)
        > if(exit condition) kill->daemon and break
    }
}
```

For daemon

```
main() (or function_name() if no execl)
{
    > initialize the arguments and IPC mechanism
    while(1)
    {
        > read command(can use simple integer/character commands)
        > perform requested action or break if exit command
    }
    > proper exit(closing file descriptors,etc.)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. The daemon is ready. What I like to have is something that I use in this way:
1) $ myDaemon # it starts, it forks, i come back to schell
2) $ ....
k) $ myDaemon doSomething # it is aleardy active (pass 1) but I can pass to it some commands when the main process is done and the forked one is left active
k+1) ...

Comment: Thanks Rahul. The daemon is ready. What I like to have is something that I use in this way:
1) $ myDaemon # it starts, it forks, i come back to schell
k) $ myDaemon doSomething # it is aleardy active (pass 1) but I can pass to it some commands when the main process is done and the forked one is left active
j) $ myDaemon stop # commands the daemon to stop
how to say, I see it simple in this way: I parse the arguments, if "start", I create the daemon and exit, if "stop" I can kill the daemon, if "doing something" I can send a message via TCP/IP to the daemon..(but not by TCP)

Comment: I've included the algorithm, if that helps.